# Passing values between two HTML elements in angular [Ionic]

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I am using ionic slide box, where I iterate over number of images and show them in the slide box

```
<ion-slide-box>
<!-- Iterate n number of times, where n is the number of images -->
  <ion-slide ng-repeat="n in [].constructor(imageCount) track by $index">
    <img ng-src="MyImage-{{$index + 1}}.png" width="100%" height="auto" > 
  </ion-slide>
</ion-slide-box>
```

Each image is identified by a counter at the end. So, if there are 5 images then this code iterates 5 times and loads images called 'MyImage_1', 'MyImage_2' etc, and shows them in the slide box.

Just below the slidebox, I am showing an edit button. When user clicks on the button, then image that is loaded in the slidebox is opened is another page for editing.

```
 <div style=" padding-bottom: 10px;">
         <a class="button button-dark icon ion-edit" ui-sref="editImage({name:'MyImage_$index'})"></a>
 </div>
```

The challenge is that how to find which image is opened in the slidebox. $index has this information but it is available only inside slidebox and not to a div outside of the slidebox.

How can I tell the anchor tag which index user is in when he clicks on the edit link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$ionicSlideBoxDelegate.currentIndex();` gives you the current index of the slide. You can know which slide you are in with current index. For more take a look at [this](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/service/$ionicSlideBoxDelegate/)